# L5 Unable to store Jquery datepicker value to database

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using L5 with eloquent. In my model i defined below function for necessary database table field.

```
public function getBuyingDateAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

Datepicker

```
$( "#buying-date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
```

I am able to display a current value with this format in my form(usingform model binding) but when i try to store or update the field the value comes null. I am a newbie with Laravel and Eloquent. How can i format and store the data properly ? Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: It's almost certainly a problem with date formats. I suspect that your datepicker is able to handle a date like "d/m/Y" (which is probably what your javascript is getting), but the model can't handle a date like "dd-mm-yy" (which is probably what the datepicker is returning).

Answer (score -1):

if in your form the date column name is date then use the following in your controller

```
$date = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($request->date));
//here $request is the object of Request class
```